# Coordinator layout with bottomnavigationview

Tags: android

I've got a problem with my CoordinatorLayout, I want my toolbar to collapse when I scroll but my BottomNavigationBar to stay visible.

Here is my layout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/activityMainWrapper"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_menu_state"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_menu_state"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

With this code the toolbar collapse on scroll, but my `FrameLayout` which contains Fragment is behind the `BottomNavigationView`.

I have tried to add a `marginBottom` to my `FrameLayout` or to remove BottomNavigationView from `CoordinatorLayout` and wrap everything into a `LinearLayout`, without effect.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try placing both `FrameLayout` and `BottomNavigationView` in `RelativeLayout`. Give `RelativeLayout` an `layout_behavior` of appbar_scrolling... In `BottomNavigationView` add `android:alignParentBottom="true"` and in `FrameLayout` add `android:layout_above="@id/bottomNavigationView"`.

Comment: `BottomNavigationView` is hidden until I scroll down.